# How to generate html TOC identifier in XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tableofcontents

I would like to generate table of content identifiers in an HTML document generated with XSL.

From the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<section>
  <header>Heading 1</header>
  <section>
    <section>
      <section>
        <header>Heading 4</header>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Heading 2</header>
    <section>
      <section>
        <section>
          <header>Heading 5</header>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Heading 3</header>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Heading 2</header>
  </section>
</section>
```

I am already able to generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
```

Thanks to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="header">
<xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::section)"/>
<xsl:element name="h{$level}">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But I need to add an additional TOC identifier to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a name="toc1"></a><h1>Heading 1</h1>
<a name="toc1_0_0_1"></a><h4>Heading 4</h4>
<a name="toc1_1"><h2>Heading 2</h2>
<a name="toc1_1_0_0_1"><h5>Heading 5</h5>
<a name="toc1_1_0_0_1_1"><h6>Heading 6</h6>
<a name="toc1_2"><h2>Heading 2</h2>
```

Is this possible with pure XSLT processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this won't quite match your current expected output, you could possible make use of the **xsl:number** element here:

```
<xsl:number count="section" level="multiple" />
```

You would need to combine this with the **translate** function to replace . with _ though. Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="header">
      <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::section)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="name">
         <xsl:number count="section" level="multiple"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <a name="{translate($name, '.', '_')}"/>
      <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would output the following:

```
<a name="1" /><h1>Heading 1</h1>
<a name="1_1_1_1" /><h4>Heading 4</h4>
<a name="1_2" /><h2>Heading 2</h2>
<a name="1_2_1_1_1" /><h5>Heading 5</h5>
<a name="1_2_2" /><h3>Heading 3</h3>
<a name="1_3" /><h2>Heading 2</h2>
```

Comment: Hi @
I am a Python developer, and I am beginner at using wkhtmltopdf, and currently I have a html being converted into a pdf. But I want to automatically include a table of contents. The documentation says I should put a file called toc.xsl into the param toc. But I am not familiar with .xsl files, so I am not sure what that file should contain. I looked online for examples, but I think they are a little beyond me. Can you please help guide me? Thanks!